# Is it detrimental to run games at the highest settings a laptop can handle?

Tags: windows, performance, system-requirements

I have only recently gotten a gaming laptop that can actually play modern games. With my old laptop, I was only capable of playing 2d games, so I'm not exactly sure about the graphics setting that I should be using on this new laptop.

I usually go for the highest pre-set graphics settings then I check whether the gameplay is smooth or not. But my concern is whether this would wear out my graphics card or my laptop in general.

**Is it generally okay to run games at the highest graphics settings that a laptop can handle?**

Comment: This is more to do with laptops and their performance than gaming.

Comment: You can't "wear out" your GPU by using it. The only way it will degrade is if it's being run at a temperature that is greater than the factory specification. If you can handle <60fps then by all means max out your GPU. As long as it isn't overheating you will do it no harm.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest concern would be to ensure you have *sufficient cooling*. Gaming *is* intensive, and a lot of regular laptops are not designed with having their GPUs and CPUs maxed out constantly in mind.

Of course, this may not be the case with a specific 'gaming laptop', but it still may be a good investment to get a Laptop Cooling pad, especially if you live in a warmer climate and/or you intend to be gaming for extended periods:

[image: Thermaltake laptop cooling pad]

They usually cost < $100. Depending on your brand of gaming laptop, there may be ones available that are specifically designed to be used with your model.

Other than that, it isn't possible to 'wear out' a GPU or CPU by running at 'maximum' all the time: The 'maximum' set in the factory is usually chosen by the maximum possible stable performance without crashing or overheating. 'Overclocking' is pushing these components past this factory limit (usually with custom cooling to achieve lower temperatures), but that's a topic for another time.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there are two ways to check wether or not you're stressing out your PC.

1 the one you said, so checking if the game runs smoothly. If this is not the case, that means your graphic card is having difficulties keeping up with the game. Lowering the settings then is vital for a good gaming experience.

2 Keep track of your processes. Use ctrl+shift+escape to see your progresses. Keep an eye out for how much CPU the game is using. Or your PC in general. E.g. When you're playing and in the meantime you're running big programs, it's possible your game will crash because your processor can't keep up. The best way to solve this is closing other CPU-consuming programs. Usually this won't be a real problem when your pc is relatively new.

Comment: Crash occurs when ram is insufficient. And about CPU usage, modern games need a robust GPU than a CPU so obviously gpu will heat up. You need to check GPU usage.(which will be full most of time while playing)